# HTML code wouldnt scroll all the way up and will not run in localhost

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web

im a newbie in html and css. im trying to make a website with a form but i have two problems:

1. My page wouldnt scroll all the way up.
2. It wouldnt launch on browser

ps: any tips to make my code cleaner or error i didnt notice will be highly appreciated

For reference here is my css code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&family=Afacad:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700;800&display=swap');


/*----------------------GENERAL STYLING--------------------*/
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  
}

body{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(140deg, #B2E2F0, white,#00b4db );
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  
}
.content button{
  justify-content: center;
}

.form-buttons{
  align-content: center;
}
.button {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #00489F;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
    align-self: center;
  }
  
  .button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  
  .button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  
  .button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
  
  .button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
  }
/*-------------------------INDEX----------------------*/
.container{
  max-width: 700px;
  height:max-content;
  width:100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding:25px 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px grey;
  align-content: center;

}
.container .title{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: center;
  align-content: center;
  border-bottom:5px solid #3E83DE;
  text-align:center;

}
.container .title h2{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:700;
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align:center;
}
.content h2{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:700;
  position:relative;
  padding: 5px;
}
.content ol li{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:700;
  position:relative;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.content h3{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:700;
  position:relative;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: grey;
}
.label {
  width: 100px; /* Set a specific width for the labels */
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right; /* Align text to the right within the label */
  margin-right: 10px; /* Adjust the margin between label and input field */
}

.input-field {
  width: 200px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
  display: inline-block;
}


  /*------------------FORM STYLING------------------------*/
  .form_container {
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 25px 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px grey;
    align-content: center;
    max-height: fit-content;
}


.biodata {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    border-bottom:#3E83DE;
    border-style: solid ;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.biodata label{
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-inline-start: 5px;

}
.biodata input{
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.form_container p {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: grey;
}

.biodata label {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0; /* Add margin to create a gap */
}

.slider_container label {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.slider_container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; /* First row for label, second row for the input */
    gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap between label and input */
    align-items: center;
}

.slider_container input[type="range"] {
    width: 300px; /* Adjust the width to your preference */
    margin-top: 5px; /* Add margin to create a gap */
    margin-bottom:5px;
    
}

.slider_container input[type="range"]::after {
    content: attr(value);
    position: relative;
    display:block; /* Adjust the distance from the slider */
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8px;

}
.slider_container input[type="range"]::before {
  content: attr(value);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px; /* Adjust the distance from the slider */
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; /* Ensure full width */
}

.med_text label {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    gap: 10px;
}

.med_text input {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.survey_form input{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
}
.button-slider p{
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.content button{
  justify-content: center;
}

.next-buttons{
  align-content: right;
}


/*-------------------------FORM PT 2 --------------------------------------*/
.form_pt2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: visibles;
}

.form_pt2 h3 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 16px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
  color: black; /* Set the text color to black */
}

.radio-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Align items horizontally */
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px; 
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button-label > p {
  font-size: 15px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
  color: black; /* Set the text color to black */
  margin: 0; /* Add margin for spacing */
}
.button-label{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-top:2px solid gray;
  
}

.radio-button > label {
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.radio-button > label > input {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.radio-button > label > h3 {
  font-size: 10px; 
  margin-top: 5px; /* Add margin for spacing between input and label */
}

.radio-button > input{
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  
}
.form_container{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I have tried overflow-y: auto and scroll both in each individual container and on body. as for the launching issue I have tried to turn off my firewall and added package.json file and launch.json as below:

```
{
  "name": "survey_form",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.html",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.